# The hdrs of cc_library seems not working of Bazel

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I'm working on a project, which depends on a third party project, let's say project `E`, which is a **precompiled** libraries. I've set a new `repository_rule` and invoked it in the `workspace.bzl`, and in the `BUILD` of the project `E`, the corresponding library rule has been set like following:

```
cc_library(
    name = "e_lib",
    srcs = [
        "@e//:e_lib1",
        "@e//:e_lib2",
    ],
    hdrs = ["@e//:e_headers"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And the target `e_lib1`, `e_lib2` and `e_headers` are defined in the file `e.BUILD`, and it is correctly symblo linked to the downloaded contents folder in the last part of implementation function of `repository_rule`.

The `e.BUILD` is something like:

```
filegroup(
    name = "e_headers",
    srcs = glob(["include/*"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "e_lib1",
    srcs = if_darwin(["lib/lib1.dylib"])
         + if_linux_x86_64(["lib/lib1.so"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "e_lib2",
    srcs = if_darwin(["lib/lib2.dylib"])
         + if_linux_x86_64(["lib/lib2.so"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Let's say there is a header `baz.h` in the directory `include` of the project `E`.But during the building phase, an error, `baz.h` file not found, occurred when bazel tried to compile a file `core.cc`. The pseudocodes are something like:

```
// core.cc
#include "core.h"
...

// core.h
#include "im.h"
...

// im.h
#include "baz.h"
// This file doesn't have the corresponding
// .cc file since all the implementations
// are put in this header.
```

The dependency of these files is `core.cc -> core.h -> im.h -> baz.h`, and the building rule of `core.cc` is:

```
cc_library(
    name = "core",
    srcs = [
        "core.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = "core.h",
    deps = [
        "//third_party/E:e_lib"],
    alwayslink = 1,
)
```

So is there something wrong with my `BUILD` file? I guess that maybe the `core.cc` doesn't directly depend on the `e_lib`, so the `deps` of it is actually useless. Should I build a `cc_library` for the `im.h`?

Comment: The root cause of this problem has been found, which is that the names of these headers also contain the relative path to them. Just add the arguments `strip_include_prefix`.

Comment: Just a best practice, you should use `cc_import` to import prebuilt library https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_import

Comment: @JohnLondon Yeah, maybe `cc_import` is more appropriate. However, there is an issue with the precompiled library on macOS, you can refer to https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4794 for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your information!